# How do you get approvals and checks configuration for a given service connection via the Azure DevOps Rest API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-rest-api, serviceconnection

I would like to retrieve existing Branch and filter configuration settings for a existing SC.

I am using below API:

"https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/checks/configurations?resourceType=<>&resourceId=<>?api-version=5.2-preview.1

But what will be the resourceId and rescourceType in this case?
Without giving this 2 parameters cant I fetch all existing configuration ?

Document Use : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/check-configurations/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

For getting a list of check configurations of a specified environment

- resourceId -> environment Id
- rescourceType -> "environment"